# TreeMap allowing null key

Tags: java, null, treemap

I am searching for a `TreeMap` that allows one `null` key. What I need is a sorted `Map<Long,String>` where I can insert one `null` key representing the default value: If the map does not contain the specified key, the value associated with the `null` key will be used.
I have been searching for this map for quite a while, but all I found was `TreeMap` which does not allow `null` keys.

Does Java have any sorted maps that allow one `null` key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps write your own. Something like this might work with some tinkering.

```
static class MapWithDefault<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
    private V dflt;

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V v = super.get(key);
        return v == null ? dflt : v;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null) {
            V was = dflt;
            dflt = value;
            return was;
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    public void setDflt(V dflt) {
        this.dflt = dflt;
    }
}
```